# Hyper-V Enhanced Session Mode not working for a user

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

A user can connect to a VM running Windows 8.1 through Virtual Machine
Connection, but is unable to listen to audio. The Admin was able to connect to the
same VM from the user’s computer and sign on using admin's credentials and
experience audio playback. What step should I take to resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy MyHusky,

The fact that you said the Administrator could login to the same VM from the User's computer in question, and get the Audio playback would suggest that the issue is centered around some sort of local or domain wide policy.  I'm not saying this is the case, but it's potentially one of a few.  Lets start here.

I know that the "answer" isn't to say "just give the user Local Admin rights", as that's not a fix, it's a band-aid, however, for the sake of ruling things out, I'd suggest that you start by giving the user at least ""Hyper-V Administrators" (if it's locally installed", try that, and then if that doesn't work, try "Power Users", then "Administrators".

Basically, the idea is to ensure that you aren't fighting a one-off obscure local policy on that Windows machine.

Remember, in Hyper-V for the Console, if it's a Gen-2 and using Enhanced Session Mode, it's actually using an embedded RDP for the console.  So by all accounts, permissions play a big role there.  You can additionally check to ensure that the Terminal Services works by passing audio through.  Try the following if this is Windows 8.1:

1. **1.  Windows Key + R (opens up the run window)

   2. Type:  mstsc  (Opens up RDP)
   3. In the Remote Desktop Connection screen, select the dropdown button "Show Options"
   4. Go to the "Local Resources" Tab, and select the "Settings" button under "Remote Audio"
   5. Ensure that it's set to "Play on This Computer"**

If you can RDP into that VM (Not the console), and get Audio, that's a good sign.  That will leave another item to check.

When you open up the Console, check the Audio Mixer to see if a new Mixer option is available for the actual VM Console, and that Windows hasn't automatically lowered or muted the volume completely.

**1. **1.  On the task tray, towards the bottom right side, click on the icon for Audio that is the speaker.  Select the "Mixer" link.

 2. Verify that all audio is turned up.  Remember, you are doing this AFTER you connect to the VM Console**.**

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced session mode works with the remote desktop functionality in windows the reason why adding the user to the local admins group works is because it is enabled for remote desktop by default. The long and short is add the user to either the local remote desktop users group or the domain group if applicable then log off and on from the VM for the change to apply.